# how to remove tags from xml using shell script

Tags: xml, shell, tags, weblogic, autodeploy

I am using a clean script to clear components from autodeploy in weblogic.This script remove all war files and restarts the weblogic domain {this script just do rm -rf * autodeploy and then restart domain using other script start and stop weblogic scripts}.This script works well, 
But sometimes,i got problems removing deployments.It removes all components from autodeploy folder  but still config.xml have "app-tag" for all components.I dont know why this is happening .but then i have to  remove these app-tag from config.xml manually.
This clean script gets in loop saying "componets getting removed"".then i have to do manual work of removing app-tags from config.xml
To avoid this manual work :
I need your help here,Is there possible way that using SHELL Script we can remove these tags from xml ??
I would like to call this script from within  my clean script.
Please guide me .

P.S : Can't post my clean script right now,But will do if needed later.Altough its just a small script which uses rm-rf and start,stop scripts

Comment: A much better option for removing WAR files from your domain is to use WLST scripting. The way you're doing it now is very error prone. See: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2215997

Comment: Actually i am using Jenkins and a job is sheduled to build in which this clean.sh first clean the app deployments and after that deployments moved to autodeploy.But,somehow this clean.sh doesnt work and gets in loop and hence job can not be finished.To end this loop we have to remove <app_tag> fromconfig.xml manually,and if we do it manually then there is no meaning of using jenkins .. Thats why i want soem script to remove these autodeployed in more efficient and good way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just removing the `<app-tag> .. </app-tag>` block, you can use sed:

```
cp -vi config.xml config.xml-ori
cat config.xml-ori | sed -e '/<app-tag>/, /<\/app-tag>/ d ' > config.xml
```

Comment: Thanks,Kuronue, i want to skip first <app -tag> to delete as this 1 single app will be same .Could you provide me some other efficient way to delete autodeployed components to avoid manual work.

Comment: Then you should avoid using `autodeploy` folder at all. It's better to use the `WLST` or `weblogic.Deployer`. They are intended for this kind of things. BTW, you dont need to restart the server for deployment -- something is wrong if you have to. It's the more reason to look at those `WLST` or `weblogic.Deployer`.